# Problema java en NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

les planteo mi problema por si alguien puede ayudarme a solucionarlo y es que tengo  un codigo de netbeans que al introducirle una cadena deberia de separarme lo que haya hasta el primer espacio y despues lo que haya entre comas.

El problema viene cuando el resultado me es correcto si al objeto de tipo Scanner que he creado le paso la cadena como tal, pero si se la paso a traves de teclado me devuelve un resultado erroneo sin el ultimo elemento entre comas.

Les dejo capturas del codigo para que lo podais ver mejor.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas dos primeras imagenes muestran el resultado de manera erronea.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y estas dos segundas imagenes muestran el resultado correcto al pasar la cadena como tal pero mi intencion es la de pasarlo por teclado.

Muchas gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda y tiempo.

Comment: Nunca he utilizado el useDelimiter. Para mi lo más cómodo si trabajas con strings es usar el método Split(). Después trabajarías de forma más sencilla, solo tendrías que pintar la salida como quieras que se vea y ya estaría.

Comment: Por favor copia directamente el código, no una imagen. Así sera mas legible y podremos ayudarte mejor.